# Is there a way to use OR condition with needs in GitLab CI job

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I am trying to create a job dependency with "OR" condition for previous stage jobs using "needs" in ".gitlab.ci.yml" file but unable to find a solution for this.

.gitlab-ci.yml file ->

```
stages:
  - build
  - test
  - deploy


Build_job:      
  stage: build
  script:
    - echo "hello from build job"

Test_job1:
  stage: test
  script:
    - echo "Start test 1"
  when: manual

Test_job2:
  stage: test
  script:
    - echo "Start test 2"
  when: manual

Deploy_job:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - echo "Start deploying the job"
  when: manual
    needs:
      - job: Test_job1
        optional: true
      - job: Test_job2
        optional: true
```

My aim is either of `Test_job1` or `Test_job2` is passed `Deploy_job` should be enabled.
But with the above code, I am unable to do so as `Deploy_job` is getting enabled only when both previous two test jobs are passed.
[image: Pipeline Status]

Is there a way if something can be used like `needs: [Test_job1 or Test_job2]`?

Comment: I think this should work out by adding: `allow_failure: true` to your `Test_job` definition.
But you need to be careful if you plan on extending the configuration in a way that includes the usage of `rules` keyword, as this might interfere with the job-level definition of `when`

Answer (score 6):

The [`needs:optional:`](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#needsoptional)  keyword is confusingly named. It is for setting up `needs:` requirements when jobs *might not exist* in the pipeline due to other pipeline/job logic (the jobs can *optionally* exist).
However, any optional `needs:job:` names that *do* exist in the pipeline will all be required.

I see a few options to get *close* to your desired pipeline:

### automation path

You could use the [`rules:`](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#rules) keyword in your Test_job jobs to conditionally add them to the pipeline.

The humans that are deciding which Test_job to run (an assumption based on the fact that you're using `when: manual`) are likely following decision logic of some sort--or a preset decision logic can be decided on by the team.  You would then build that logic into your `needs:if:` condition to determine whether or not your `Test_job#` jobs *exist* in the pipeline--then only the Test_jobs that are added to the pipeline will be required by the `Deploy_job:`.

For example, if one test should run on your default branch and the other on feature branches, you could use the following to automatically run the relevant Test_job and have the Deploy_job depend on it:

```yaml
Test_job1:
  stage: test
  script:
    - echo "Start test 1"
  # this job is only added for pipelines on the default branch
  rules:
    - if $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME == $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH
      when: on_success
    - when: never

Test_job2:
  stage: test
  script:
    - echo "Start test 2"
  # this job is only added for pipelines NOT on the default branch
  rules:
    - if $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME != $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH
      when: on_success
    - when: never

Deploy_job:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - echo "Start deploying the job"
  # this is the default value, it's added here to show the automation difference from the question's pipeline
  rules:
    - when: on_success
  # depend on Test_job1 AND Test_job2 if they individually exist in the pipeline
  needs:
    - job: Test_job1
      optional: true
    - job: Test_job2
      optional: true
```

### manual path

You could swap `when:manual` back in place for `when:on_success` if you still need humans in the loop on triggering the test jobs or deploy job.

### really manual path

*Alternatively*, if you really just want your humans to manually make the `Test_job:` decisions ad-hoc, then just remove the `needs:` keyword from your `Deploy_job:` and use the existing Stage dependency structure.  The `when: manual` key implicitly sets `allow_failure: true`, so your jobs are already optional as is.  If your humans can't be trusted to manage the "Test before Deploy" dependency on their own with manual jobs, then take the humans out of the loop and see the "automation path" above.