# how to add a "needs" based on a condition

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

Is there a way to add a need in order for a job to run? Or is there a specific way to add a condition if you're on a specific branch, please add this job as a dependency? So far I have a "need"s within my rules section. Review job only runs on feature branches. There is a [similar question being asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72404581/is-there-a-way-to-use-or-condition-with-needs-in-gitlab-ci-job).

```
test:sauce:
  ...
  script:
    - export MASTER_URL=https://masterurlexample.io
    - export TEST_PREVIEW_APP=$CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG
    - cd $MAVEN_DIRECTORY
    - if [ "$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH" == "master" || "$EMULATE_BRANCH" == "master" ]; then
        export TEST_PREVIEW_APP=$MASTER_URL;
        needs:
      fi;
    - echo "Testing on $TEST_PREVIEW_APP"
    - echo "starting test"
    - sleep 30
    - mvn -U $MAVEN_CLI_OPTS ...
  rules:
    - if: "$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH" != "master"
      needs: [ "review "]
```

Answer (score 3):

Check if [GitLab 16.1](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2023/06/22/gitlab-16-1-released/#cicd-use-needs-in-rules) (June 2023) can help:

> ### CI/CD: Use needs in rules
>
> The [`needs:`](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#needs) keyword defines a dependency relationship between jobs, which you can use to set jobs to run out of stage order.
>
> In this release we’ve added the ability to define this relationship for specific `rules` conditions.
>
> When a condition matches a rule, the job’s `needs` configuration is completely replaced with the `needs` in the rule.
>
> This can help speed up a pipeline based on your defined conditions, when a job can start earlier than normal.
> You can also use this to force a job to wait for an earlier one to complete before starting, you now have more flexible `needs` options!
>
> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#rulesneeds) and [Issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/31581).

Example of `rules:needs`:

```yaml
build-dev:
  stage: build
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH != $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH
  script: echo "Feature branch, so building dev version..."

build-prod:
  stage: build
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH
  script: echo "Default branch, so building prod version..."

specs:
  stage: test
  needs: ['build-dev']
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME == $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH
      needs: ['build-prod']
    - when: on_success # Run the job in other cases
  script: echo "Running dev specs by default, or prod specs when default branch..."
```

In this example:

- If the pipeline runs on a branch that is not the default branch, the specs job needs the `build-dev` job (default behavior).
- If the pipeline runs on the default branch, and therefore the rule matches the condition, the specs job needs the `build-prod` job instead.

Answer (score 1):

I think is not possible.

A workaround could be make a template job (starting the name with `.`) cointaining your code and extends the job two time, one time for the case `"$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH" != "master"` with `needs: [ "review "]` and another time with `- if: "$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH" == "master"` without the needs section.

EDIT:
I try to explain myself better, my idea is to use an hidden job like

```
.hidden_job:
  script:
    - YOUR CODE HERE
```

And after that extended this job into others with the right needs setted, like:

```
job1:
  extends: .hidden_job
  rules:
    - if: "$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH" != "master"
    needs: [ "review "]


job2:
  extends: .hidden_job
  rules:
    - if: "$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH" == "master"
```

In this way you can define multiple job with different rules and needs for satisfy your requirements without repeating your code everytime. (E.G. use a specific needs only on a specific branch, like job1)

Comment: What do you mean by extends the job?

Comment: I edited my answer to better explain myself